# Hudson Job Completion with Cargo

Tags: maven-2, hudson, cargo

I am using cargo maven plugin to start weblogic server (mvn cargo:run). Everything is working fine but hudson job is not getting completed. Is there any way by which hudson job can be completed after server start up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We are using maven-weblogic-plugin instead of maven-cargo-plugin which tells you clearly when server is started/stopped etc. Hudson jobs are working fine with this.